# Using iOS storyboarding I can't place label in spot I want on view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard

Dragging immediately drops it somewhere in the beginning where I don't want it... I'm looking to put it in the top center.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jaime It's a solution but not best. The top bar called UINavigationBar which already has title to display in the top center. So you should drag out a navigation item to view controller and set its title.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, problem was the ViewController did not have a view on it. Adding a view and dragging the label on top of it fixed it.

[image]